# Define a Class Property using IF statements with existing Properties

Tags: vba, excel, class

I have a Class, called **cMilestones** which I have multiple properties set, some are `Date`, some are `Integer` and some `String`.

**The Problem/Challenge** : I am stuck, I want to use the `Let` and `Get Property` statements, but to use already defined Properties of the Class (called *CommittedDate* and *UncommittedDate*).

***PlanDate* Property Conditions**:

1. `If IsDate(CommittedDate) Then PlanDate = CommittedDate`
2. Else: `If IsDate(UnCommittedDate) Then PlanDate = UnCommittedDate`
3. Else : raise error flag somehow

Here is my  **cMilestones Class** code so far (working part) ...

```
Private pMilestoneName                  As String
Private pCommittedDate                  As Date
Private pUncommittedDate                As Date
Private pPlanDate                       As Date
Private pmsRow                          As Integer
Private pmsRowPlan                      As Integer
Private pmsRowAct                       As Integer
Private pmsHgt_Up                       As Single
Private pmsHgt_Down                     As Single

' --- Get/Let Methods ---

Public Property Get MilestoneName() As String
    MilestoneName = pMilestoneName
End Property

Public Property Let MilestoneName(value As String)
    pMilestoneName = value
End Property


Public Property Get CommittedDate() As Date
    CommittedDate = pCommittedDate
End Property

Public Property Let CommittedDate(value As Date)
    If IsDate(value) Then
        pCommittedDate = value
    End If
End Property


Public Property Get UncommittedDate() As Date
    UncommittedDate = pUncommittedDate
End Property

Public Property Let UncommittedDate(value As Date)
    If IsDate(value) Then
        pUncommittedDate = value
    End If
End Property
```

**Not Working yet...**

```
' ****** This is where I am not able to make it work *******
Public Property Get PlanDate(pCommittedDate As Date) As Date
    PlanDate = pPlanDate
End Property

' ****** This is where I am not able to make it work *******
Public Property Let PlanDate(pCommittedDate As Date, pUncommittedDate As Date)
'Public Sub PlanDate(pCommittedDate As Date, pUncommittedDate As Date)

    If IsDate(pCommittedDate) Then
        pPlanDate = pCommittedDate
    Else
        If IsDate(pUncommittedDate) Then
            pPlanDate = pUncommittedDate
        Else
            ' Milestone doesn't have Committed or Uncommitted plan >> raise Error Flag

        End If            
    End If

End Property
```

And this is my **Sub** where I am using an array to store a lot of milestones using the class objects:

```
Public Sub ReadMilestonesRange_toClass()    

i = 0
DataRow = FirstRow
LastExistingMSRow = DataRow

' loop through all milestones in Column A to find the latest Row that has Milestone Name in it
While DataRow <= LastMSRow
    Set ProjMilestones = New cMilestones
    ProjMilestones.MilestoneName = Cells(DataRow, 1)
    ProjMilestones.MSRow = DataRow

    ProjMilestones.CommittedDate = Cells(DataRow, 2)
    ProjMilestones.UncommittedDate = Cells(DataRow, 3)

    ' ****** Want to add the PlanDate to my cMilestones Class array ******
    ProjMilestones.PlanDate (ProjMilestones.UncommittedDate)
    ProjMilestones.ForecastDate = Cells(DataRow, 4)
    ProjMilestones.ActualDate = Cells(DataRow, 5)

    If ProjMilestones.MilestoneName <> "" Then
        ReDim Preserve ProjArrMilestones(0 To i)
        Set ProjArrMilestones(i) = ProjMilestones
        i = i + 1
        LastExistingMSRow = DataRow

    End If
    Set ProjMilestones = Nothing

    DataRow = DataRow + 1
Wend
MilestonesNum = LastExistingMSRow - FirstRow + 1 ' Total of Milestones in Milestone Table

      Set ProjMilestones = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: If you are passing `Date` parameters, there really isn't a lot of point in testing them with `IsDate`.

Comment: @Rory they are copied from Sheet.Cells, sometime it can be blank, so I don't want to get the error, each of of the Milestones can either have a Committed date or Uncommitted date, so I want the property Plan date to search for one of the two. If both are empty, I need to raise a flag to the user he has an error.

Comment: You misunderstand. By declaring the parameters as `Date` you **can't** pass anything else, so you'll never get to the `IsDate` part if what you try to pass is not a date - you'll simply get a runtime mismatch error.

Comment: @Rory I am relatively new with working with Classes in VBA, this is why I am posting this.

Comment: It's nothing to do with it being a class. You have a routine declared to only accept `Date` parameters. Therefore trying to pass anything else will result in a runtime error. You need to test the values **before you try and assign them to the property**, not *in* the property. Or you need to change the declaration to accept `Variant` rather than `Date` types.

Comment: @Rory these are just my code attempts of trying to resolve the issue in my post. I realy don't know how to set it up, if I need to get these 2 parameters (maybe I can read them from inside the class), how do I check if the current member of this class has either one of these dates ?

Comment: You haven't actually explained **how** you are trying to use them (neither of the other properties is used in your code) or what your actual problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pCommittedDate` and  `pUncommittedDate` are class fields, so they're right available inside any class instance and therefore you don't want to pass them as parameters to `Property Get PlanDate()` and `Property Let PlanDate()` methods.

Hence, you only need to check them against `0` value to see if already initialized

So code like this:

```
Public Property Get PlanDate() As Date
    PlanDate = pPlanDate
End Property


Public Property Let PlanDate(value As Date)
    If pCommittedDate <> 0 Then 'if pCommittedDate is already "initialized"
        pPlanDate = pCommittedDate
    Else
        If pUncommittedDate <> 0 Then 'if pUncommittedDate is already "initialized"
            pPlanDate = pUncommittedDate
        Else
            ' Milestone doesn't have Committed or Uncommitted plan >> raise Error Flag

        End If
    End If
End Property
```

This way your code runs but with `PlanDate` being quite a *weird* property since its `Let` accessor would require a `value` with no use at all!

Since you don't seem to want `PlanDate` to be set by the class consumer, just turn it to a plain class field:

```
Public PlanDate As Date

'...

Public Property Get CommittedDate() As Date
    CommittedDate = pCommittedDate
End Property

Public Property Let CommittedDate(value As Date)
        pCommittedDate = value            
        PlanDate = pCommittedDate '<--| set PlanDate as well
End Property


Public Property Get UncommittedDate() As Date
    UncommittedDate = pUncommittedDate
End Property

Public Property Let UncommittedDate(value As Date)
        pUncommittedDate = value
        If pCommittedDate = 0 Then PlanDate = pUncommittedDate '<--| set PlanDate only if 'pCommittedDate' is not initialized (changed pPlanDate  to PlanDate)
End Property
```

where you get rid of all those If `IsDate(value)` since you already declare `value as Date` so an error would occur anyhow at the class consumer code should it ever try to set any `Date` value with an invalid one

here's a possible exploitation of the class as per above last code

```
Sub main()
    Dim myvar As New cMilestones

    With myvar
        .CommittedDate = "1/1/2015" '<--| this will define 'PlanDate' as well
        .UncommittedDate = "31/12/2105" '<--| this will NOT redefine 'PlanDate', since 'CommittedDate' is already defined

        .PlanDate = "1/1/2016" '<--| this will redefine 'PlanDate'...
    End With
End Sub
```

So the question is: is it really necessary to have `PlanDate` set by the class consumer?

Comment: I have 2 question: how do I call them from my Sub (see my edited post above). There is a sitation where both `CommittedDate` and `UncommittedDate` will be blank (forgotten to be written by the user), I want to raise a flag with an Error MsgBox to follow.

Comment: I'll have a look at the edited question. In the meanwhile if I fulfilled your _original_ question please mark it as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If need to use an array to pass multiple values to a Property.

```
milestone.PlanDate = Arrray(#1/1/2016#, #2/1/2016#)
```

Or

```
milestone.PlanDate = Range("A1:B1").Value
```

---

```
Public Property Let PlanDate(arrDates() As Variant)    
    If IsDate(arrDates(0)) Then
        pPlanDate = arrDates(0)
    Else
        If IsDate(arrDates(1)) Then
            pPlanDate = arrDates(1)
        Else
            ' Milestone doesn't have Committed or Uncommitted plan >> raise Error Flag

        End If
    End If

End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

In your accessor for PlanDate, you need an argument pCommitedDate - but you're not using this variable in your body -thereby it's pretty irrelevant to parse this parameter.

```
Public Property Get PlanDate(pCommittedDate As Date) As Date
    PlanDate = pPlanDate
End Property
```

If you want to assign pPlanDate to `CommittedDate` or `UnCommittedDate`, you can do this easily by just adding this to your body.

For your modifier, try using the Debug.Print output to check your input-variables values. Anyways you can modify your code to this:

```
Public Property Let PlanDate(pCommittedDate As Date, pUncommittedDate As Date)

    If IsDate(pCommittedDate) Then
        pPlanDate = pCommittedDate
    ElseIf IsDate(pUncommittedDate) Then
        pPlanDate = pUncommittedDate
    Else
        ' Print to immediate-window
        Debug.Print "pCommittedDate or pUncommittedDate failed"
    End If      

End Property
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let's deal with Rory's very valid point first:

If you declare a variable as `Date` then the test `IsDate(var)` will always return `True` because a date value is assigned when the variable is initialised. Try this code to prove it:

```
Dim dat As Date

Debug.Print dat
Debug.Print IsDate(dat)
```

The output will be:

> 12:00:00 a.m.
>
> True

There are several ways of flagging when a property has received a value, and perhaps the easiest would be simply to set a boolean flag. Like so:

```
Private pDate1 As Date
Private pDate1IsSet As Boolean

Public Property Let Date1(val As Date)
    pDate1 = val
    pDate1IsSet = True
End Property
```

If you ran the following module code

```
Dim oSchedule As clsSchedule

Set oSchedule = New clsSchedule
Debug.Print oSchedule.Date1IsSet & " " & oSchedule.Date1
oSchedule.Date1 = #1/21/2014#
Debug.Print oSchedule.Date1IsSet & " " & oSchedule.Date1
```

then the output would be:

> False 12:00:00 a.m.
>
> True 21/01/2014

In your case, though, it might just be simpler to set your `pPlanDate` variable in each of the other two date setters, like so:

```
Private pDate1 As Date
Private pDate2 As Date
Private pTheDate As Date

Public Property Let Date1(val As Date)
    pDate1 = val
    pTheDate = val
End Property

Public Property Let Date2(val As Date)
    pDate2 = val
    pTheDate = val
End Property

Public Property Get TheDate() As Date
    TheDate = pTheDate
End Property
```

Finally, if you do need to test if no date has been set, then perhaps that should be a property of your class. You could even prioritise the desired date, like so:

```
Private pDate1 As Date
Private pDate2 As Date
Private pTheDate As Date
Private pDateIsSet As Boolean

Public Property Let Date1(val As Date)
    pDate1 = val
    pTheDate = val
    pDateIsSet = True
End Property

Public Property Let Date2(val As Date)
    pDate2 = val
    If Not pDateIsSet Then
        pTheDate = val
        pDateIsSet = True
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get TheDate() As Date
    TheDate = pTheDate
End Property

Public Property Get DateIsSet() As Boolean
    DateIsSet = pDateIsSet
End Property
```

To my eye, this makes the following code easier to read and, to my mind at least, provides a class object that contains the properties specific to its purpose. Food for thought perhaps in your class design considerations?

```
Dim oSchedule As clsSchedule

Set oSchedule = New clsSchedule
oSchedule.Date1 = #1/21/2014#
If oSchedule.DateIsSet Then
    Debug.Print oSchedule.TheDate
Else
    Debug.Print "No date"
End If
```

Comment: What happens if from my sub that calls the Class, I am reading a cell range that has a string ? Or it's blank ? I don't want to get an error.

Comment: It depends on your design architecture, but you basically have 3 options: 1. Test the cell values, validate them within your 'reading' routine, and only pass valid cells to the class; 2. Create a data validation routine within the class itself and populate the property fields only with valid data; 3) Pass the 'raw data' range through some kind of 'cleansing' function, say at Module level, which returns a range of only valid cells for 'reading'.

Comment: I want to adapt the second approach , I want to empower the class

Comment: Cool. Some people prefer to have an architecture where data validation takes place outside of the class in order to retain the 'pure' purpose of the class - I have to say I'm one - but it's entirely up to you.